# Can't Access WCF Service from Phonegap?

Tags: wcf, cordova

I had created WCF services which host sub.xyz.com and I can access it from abc.xyz.com as well sub.xyz.com successfully.

While I can't access WCF services through Phonegap Application.

It shows me error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://sub.xyz.com' (Check in Ripple Emulator) is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503."

I had also put support.cors=true; but can't able to connect with WCF service.

$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {

```
          $.support.cors = true;
```

});

Comment: All your external sources have to be whitelisten, please read the docs.

Comment: I had also tried it <access origin="xyz.com" subdomains="true" /> but still get error and when its access origin="*" /> that time also getting same error.